# How to create a custom Scrollbar for a particular section in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, css, slds

I am new to LWC and SLDS Designs. I have a certain design of a scrollbar I need to create but unable to get how to get this specific design. I need the scrollbar at the greyed out section. The Values will be coming in from Apex server side and I will populate them
[image]

I searched for the Scrollable Documentation in Lightning Design System : [SLDS Scrollable](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/scrollable/#Y-Axis)
But this is the design and look
[image]

Here is my code

HTML

```
<lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open  active-section-name={activeSections}>
 <h2 class="slds-panel__header-title slds-text-heading_small slds-truncate slds-account-header" title="Panel Header">{labels.filters}</h2>
<lightning-accordion-section name="A" label={labels.div} class="" lwc:if={divisionFilterOptions.length}>
   <div class="slds-p-left_x-large slds-p-vertical_medium filter-list">
<lightning-checkbox-group name="Checkbox Group"
                   variant="label-hidden"
                    options={divisionFilterOptions}
                   value={value}
                   onchange={handleDivisionFilterChange}>
</lightning-checkbox-group>
    </div> 
  </lightning-accordion-section>
 </lightning-accordion>
```

CSS

```
.filter-box{
    background: var(--white);
    box-shadow: 0 0.125rem 0.9375rem #bbbbbb40;
    border-radius: 0.125rem;
}
.filter-list{
    background-color: var(--lightgray);
}
```

this is how it presently looks. This needs to show 4-5 options like this with the blue scrollbar and for more we can scroll

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will work for you.
You can change code according to you. This is just sample code

HTML

```
<template>
    <div class="app">
        <div class="scrollbar style-3">
            <div class="force-overflow">
                <input type="checkbox"></input> &nbsp;Option 1
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox"></input> &nbsp;Option 2
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox"></input> &nbsp;Option 3
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox"></input> &nbsp;Option 4
                <br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

CSS

```
.app {
    background-color: #fafaf9;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.scrollbar
{
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.force-overflow
{
    min-height: 450px;
    padding: 1em;
}

.style-3::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.style-3::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 6px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.style-3::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    background-color: #49a1e4;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Hi Karan. This looks good but if u see my arrow in the picture I posted which I need the blue scrollbar is having a grey long line below (kind of a boundary) where the blue scroll section will go down. How I can get that?. Also can u make the changes in my code snippet so I can use it?